# How can I center a list in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my website `https://acanhs.org/nhs-articles.html` I want to center the list so it looks nicer. How can I do that? I tried using the `<center>` tag but had no luck. I would like to centre the name and date under the article name to make it look nicer

This is my html:

```css
a:link {
  color: Black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: Black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: Black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: Black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ACA NHS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<center>
  <section class="blog-posts grid-system">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="all-blog-posts">
            <center>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb"><img src="assets/images/blog-thumb-01.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      <h4>الأمير الراحل … أمير الإنسانية</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Mohammad Al-Obaidi</li><br>
                        <li>3/10/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/الأمير الراحل … أمير الإنسانية.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb"><img src="assets/images/blog-thumb-02.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      <h4>Uyghur Muslims</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Khalid Kooheji</li><br>
                        <li>27/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/Uyghur Muslims.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb"><img src="assets/images/blog-thumb-02.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="down-content" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/Corona Virus A New World.pdf';">
                      <h4>Corona Virus: A New World</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Majed Al-Shaheen</li><br>
                        <li>27/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download">
                        <div class="cloud">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb"><img src="assets/images/blog-thumb-03.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      <h4>التعلم عبادة</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Omar Sheir</li><br>
                        <li>23/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/التعلم عبادة.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="blog-thumb"><img src="assets/images/blog-thumb-04.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="down-content">
                      <h4>الصدقة</h4>
                      <ul class="post-info">
                        <li>Ahmad Al-Mazrouei</li><br>
                        <li>20/9/2020</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="btn download" onclick="window.location='articlepdfs/الصدقة.pdf';">
                        <div class="cloud">
                          <div class="arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-options">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: which list specifically?

Comment: Please only post relative code and try to make a snippet with the `[<>]` button

Comment: It’s really hard to help when there is so much code which seems unrelated.

Comment: @Reyno I'm sorry I'm new here. How can I do that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh sorry about that. I removed the unrelated parts

Comment: You had a missing </style>

Comment: And no opening `<body>` tag (as the syntax highlighting shows).

Comment: Semantically speaking you can't have a `<br>` as an `<ul>` child element. Just `<li>` elements are allowed.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. I'm new to web development and html

Comment: @melancia: that's not "*semantically speaking*" that's simply the rules of HTML; inspecting the DOM should show those `<br>` elements being moved - by the browser - out of the `<ul>`.

Comment: The `<center>` element has been long made obsolete. Rely on CSS to achieve the same result. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: Well pointed out @DavidsaysreinstateMonica. I was just being polite. :)

Comment: Is there any way you could merge the 2 `<li>` elements into 1? E.g. `<li>Name | Date</li>`?

Comment: Incidentally the list looks like it's centred already, in that the names and dates appear to be horizontally centred beneath the `<h4>` element text. What's wrong with the current appearance that you're trying to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your content is generated is causing you a few headaches, along with your `float: left` for each `<li>`.

**Solution 1: Generate your HTML differently**

This might not be viable, but if you could put it in just 1 tag (e.g. `<p>Name | Date</p>`) then it would solve your problem.

**Solution 2: Display inline-block**

I've removed pretty much all your styling for `li` elements. The only rule I have is:

```css
li{
   display: inline-block;
}

.blog-posts .down-content ul.post-info li:after {
    content: '|';
    color: #aaa;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

This puts both `li` tags onto the same line but doesn't open you up to any `float` issues. Because the content is already centered, your text is centered too. You do have this set up, but in `stylesheet.css` on line 81 you are overriding this!!!

Comment: This actually worked! I did have to re edit the navbar and set up a new class for all the li's but it worked!

Comment: No worries - happy to help!